# use a service inside a funcion

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and angular.

At this moment I want to use translateService inside the point formatter function:

```
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
}
private getOptions() {
  return {
    name: this.name,
    color: this.color,
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function () {
        /* this line is my problem, how to use this.translateService here! */
        const myTranslation = translateService.instant('KEY', {value:this.y});
        return `<span>\u25CF</span> ${myTranslation}`;
      }
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IIFE to store `this` from the outer scope:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter: (function(component) {
    return function() {
      console.log(this, component);
    }
  })(this)
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4918/

Comment: this is not working because in this way I can use translateService, but I cant use the selected y value

Comment: Hi @cucuru, That is not true, have you tested the code?

Comment: of course i tested, with your fiddle where you print the component, and i can use it, but not able to use the selected point. If you are so sure, please update your example to see how to get the selected point. Thanks

Comment: In the internal function `this` refers to the selected point. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qs3dzk4y/

Answer (score 1):

Using `function() { }` syntax will scope `this` to the function itself. To scope `this` to the outer scope - to be able to interact with the service declared outside of the function - use an arrow function and call `this.translateService`.

```js
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
}
private getOptions() {
  return {
    name: this.name,
    color: this.color,
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: () => {
        const myTranslation = this.translateService.instant('KEY', {value:this.y});
        return `<span>\u25CF</span> ${myTranslation}`;
      }
    },
  };
}
```

You are already using `this` inside the function, so there's a chance that you will have to investigate another way of getting `this.y`. Maybe it's passed in as an arg, or maybe it's declare outside and you just chosen to omit it from the question as unecessary detail?

Comment: this is not working because in this way I can use translateService, but I cant use the selected y value

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that. Does the callback receive any args?