# highcharts, use external function but get highcharts data

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm using highcharts in angular and trying to configure a personal tooltip.

My problem is I need to use the data that I have in my angular component and the point selected in the tooltip, so, if I use this structure:

```
pointFormatter: function () {
     // here I have this.x and this.y as the selected point
     // but I have no access to external functions
}
```

and if I use this one:

```
pointFormatter: () => {
  // here I have access to external functions
  // but I have no access to the selected point
}
```

How can I do it to have access to both to be able to calculate my tooltip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use a service inside a funcion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718272/use-a-service-inside-a-funcion)

Comment: hi, thanks, no, with this solutions I have the same problem, I have external functions or selected point, but I have no both at the same time

Comment: Let's continue this thread in the previous question.